# perl - remove bytes from a binmode string by looking up an array

Tags: perl

I'm reading file in chunks using binmode() and wanted to strip out byte values that match any value in a static list

```
@strip = (91,   92,   98,   107,   5,   64,   21,   13,   11,   12)
```

what I'm doing in my script

```
binmode($fh);
read($fh,$data,20);
%strip = (91=>1, 92=>1,98=>1,107=>1,5=>1,64=>1,21=>,13=>1,11=>1,12=>1); 
$data=~s/(.)/$strip{ord($1)} ? "" :$1/ge
```

I'm afraid, doing it regex way might be incorrect and have some undesirable results.

Can someone suggest alternative ways that is cleaner and efficient to achieve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex engine is perfectly happy to operate on strings of bytes (though using `\d` and such may not make any sense), so your approach is perfectly fine. But white quite efficient, it can be sped up.

What if we used `chr` on the bytes to strip rather than using `ord` on all the characters read?

```
my @to_strip = ( 5, 11, 12, 13, 21, 64, 91, 92, 98, 107 );
my %to_strip = map { chr($_) => 1 } @to_strip;

$data =~ s/(.)/ $strip{$1} ? "" :$1 /ge;
```

What if we took it a step further, and made the replacement choice even sooner?

```
my @to_strip = ( 5, 11, 12, 13, 21, 64, 91, 92, 98, 107 );
my %to_strip = map { chr($_) => 1 } @to_strip;
my %map = map { $to_strip{$_} ? "" : $_ } map chr, 0x00..0xFF;

$data =~ s/(.)/$map{$1}/sg;
```

But we're still doing a lot of needless replacements. What if we search for the specific character we want to replace?

```
my @to_strip = ( 5, 11, 12, 13, 21, 64, 91, 92, 98, 107 );
my $pat = "[" . quotemeta( pack( 'C*', @to_strip ) ) . "]+";
my $re = qr/$pat/;

$data =~ s/$re//g;
```

This one is much faster for three reasons:

- As previously mentioned, we greatly reduced the number of matches, which reduces the number of times the replacement expression needs to be evaluated and concatenated.
- The regex engine can check for matching characters far faster than our Perl code can.
- We eliminated the need for captures, which are (relatively speaking) quite slow.

Remember that `@to_strip`, `%to_strip`, `%map`, `$pat` and `$re` only need to be calculated once, not once per `read`. When I talked about speed above, I wasn't including the time needed to calculate these, since I assumed you will be doing multiple reads and replaces.

---

That said, if it's reasonable to hardcode the bytes to remove, `tr///d` will give you the best performance.

```
$data =~ tr/\x05\x0B-\x0D\x15\x40\x5B\x5C\x62\x6B//d;
```

It's not effective to use `tr///` from a dynamic list because `tr///` doesn't interpolate. We have to resort to building a sub, and invoking a sub is relatively slow.

```
my @to_strip = ( 5, 11, 12, 13, 21, 64, 91, 92, 98, 107 );
my $class = quotemeta( pack( 'C*', @to_strip ) );
my $inline_stripper = eval("sub { $_[0] =~ tr/$class//d; }");

$inline_stripper->($data);
```

---

The following is an efficient (but surely not as efficient) non-regex approach.

```
my @to_strip = ( 5, 11, 12, 13, 21, 64, 91, 92, 98, 107 );
my @to_strip_lookup; $to_strip_lookup[$_] = 1 for @to_strip;

$data = pack 'C*', grep !$to_strip_lookup[$_], unpack 'C*', $data
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.. will not using chr() on a binmode string change characters

Comment: Re "*will not using chr() on a binmode string change characters*", huh? None of the solutions use `chr` on a string.

Comment: just curious..  this is something like A minus B set operation, so can it be done with 2 arrays of byte values?.

Comment: You could consider the list of bytes to strip a set, but not the data because the values of sets are unique and unordered. But you aren't wrong. The non-regex solution is I've just added is basically exactly how I'd do a set difference (if the elements of the sets started in arrays): `my %B = map { $_ => 1 } @B; my @AminusB = grep !$B{$_}, @A;`

Comment: `list2re` from [Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge) can nicely wrap the logic of creating the regex (though I don't know if the resulting regex will be as efficient as a character class in this case).

Comment: @Grinnz, `list2re` doesn't perform any optimizations (unlike Regexp::Assemble, though most of the optimizations might not be needed since Perl switched to using tries for alternations), but it does help handle a couple corner cases.

Comment: how about ````tr//d```` instead of ````$data =~ s/$re//g````

Comment: tr/// would be a good choice for this problem as well (and wouldn't require the quotemeta step).

Comment: tr/// would be fastest and quite simple if the bytes to remove were hardcoded (though it would definitely still require some form of encoding/escaping contrary to what Grinnz says). On the other hand, using tr/// with a dynamic liste of character would be far more complex (because you can't interpolate into tr///). You'd have to build a whole sub dynamically, and call the sub to do the replace. But since subs are quire slow to call (relatively speaking), it would outweigh the benefit of switching tr/// except for very long strings.